# Magento column grid default filter value

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, sales-order, backend

I want to have a default value in a column on sales grid, the value will be the actual day.

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
        'index' => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',

        'value'=>array(
            'from'=>date('Y-m-d', time())
        )
    ));
```

But its not working and I don't know why.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
    'index' => 'created_at',
    'type' => 'datetime',
    'width' => '100px',
    'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',

    'value'=>array(
        'from'=>date('Y-m-d')
    )
));
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have, but I solved with the method  `$this->setDefaultFilter( $arrayFilter ); `

Answer (score 2):

In the `_prepareColumns` method of my custom class extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` I was able to set a filter like this:

```
$this->setDefaultFilter(array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));
```

or

```
$this->setDefaultFilter(array('name' => 'foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**File Path:**

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

Put your code these way You can See Only actual day

```
  $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
    'index' => 'created_at',
    'type' => 'date',
    'width' => '100px',
));
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have, but I solved with the method `$this->setDefaultFilter( $arrayFilter );`