# Magento - Set default filter of customer attribute in order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, grid, backend, order-grid

I've just managed to include a custom customer attribute in the order grid columns like this:

```
$agenteAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'agente');
$agenteTable = $agenteAttribute->getBackendTable();
$agenteId = $agenteAttribute->getAttributeId();
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('ca' => $agenteTable),
    'ca.attribute_id='.$agenteId.' AND ca.entity_id =main_table.customer_id',
    array('agente'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('ca.value')
    )
);
```

But when I try to search in the filter field of the order grid, I get this log error:

> Unknown column 'agente' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`agente` LIKE '%312%')";i:1;s:5885:"#0

I tried these two functions but without success:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('agente',array('in' => array(313)));
$this->setDefaultFilter(array('agente'=>312));
```

How can I do?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

FIND SOLUTION! I hope this can serve someone else:
In app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php i inserted this code in _prepareCollection():

`protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());`

$agenteAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'agente');
    $agenteTable = $agenteAttribute->getBackendTable();
    $agenteId = $agenteAttribute->getAttributeId();

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('ca' => $agenteTable),
    'ca.attribute_id='.$agenteId.' AND ca.entity_id = main_table.customer_id',
    array('agente'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('ca.value')
    )
);
```

$collection->addFilterToMap("agente","ca.value");

$collection->addFieldToFilter('agente', array('in', attribute_value));

Comment: See also this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164330/magento-column-grid-default-filter-value/245797#245797